# Adaptive Images issue on Bitnami Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, bitnami

I am using a Amazon Bitnami Ubuntu Server to run Wordpress. I use the theme called Uncode, in this theme there is a feature included called "Asynchronous Adaptive Images". What it basically does it handles the loading speed of the images. (first the picture will be displayed unsharp and immediately after that it replaces it with the sharp one).
When I use the webpage on an iPhone in private surf mode the images stay unsharp. There is nothing wrong with the settings or the theme, I switched from my old server to an Amazon and since then I have the issue. I tried to google and found this by the developer of the theme I am using:

https://support.undsgn.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003945345-Blurry-Images-Troubleshoot

I think it has something to do with the caching system on my server. Is there any setting you have to enable on bitnami or do I have to install something that fixes the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami WordPress stack includes during its installation the possibility (enabled by default) of use Varnish. I think that could be affecting your plugin. You could try to disable it doing `sudo INSTALLDIR/ctlscript stop varnish`.

Comment: I think Varnish is not installed: bitnami@ip-172-31-32-11:~$ sudo INSTALLDIR/ctlscript stop varnish
sudo: INSTALLDIR/ctlscript: command not found